# Javascript Passing information

Tags: javascript, ruby

I am new to Javascript and trying to make a simple calculator web app.  Below is the following code and was wondering how to pass the information of the onclick events to the textbox that appears.  As you can see I am also using Ruby.  Is it not possible to use both Ruby and Javascript?  Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

```
<INPUT TYPE="text"   NAME="Input" Size="16">

<% numbers_3 = [7, 8, 9] %>
<% numbers_2 = [4, 5, 6] %>
<% numbers_1 = [1, 2, 3] %>

<br>

<%  numbers_3.each do |number| %>
  <%= button_tag number %>
<%    end %>
<%= button_tag "x" %>

<br>

<%  numbers_2.each do |number| %>
  <%= button_tag number %>
<%    end %>
<%= button_tag "-" %>

<br>

<%  numbers_1.each do |number| %>
  <%= button_tag number %>
<%    end %>
<%= button_tag "+" %>

<br>


<%= button_tag "c" %> <script> VALUE="  c  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '' "> </script>
<%= button_tag "0" %> <script> VALUE="  0  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '0' "></script>
<%= button_tag "." %> <script> VALUE="  .  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '.' "></script>
<%= button_tag "=" %> <script> VALUE="  =  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value = eval(Calc.Input.value)"></script>
```

Comment: You might also have some kind of name conflict due to case (in)sensitivity issues, e.g. `Calc.Input` vs `form.input`. Try changing `name="Calc.Input"` to something more unique using an id, e.g. `id="CalcInput"`, and the js accordingly: `var elt = document.getElementById('CalcInput'); elt.value = eval(elt.value);`

Comment: Are you using Ruby-on-Rails? That's very different from just using Ruby.

Comment: This is also a real mess. There are numerous syntax issues that would prevent this from even parsing, never mind actually running. Just try to sort out the syntax problems in `<%= button_tag "c" %> <script> VALUE="  c  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '' "> </script>
` first. Hint, you're missing semi-colons and you have an extra `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's too much wrong here to point it all out. No part of this is correctly implemented:

```
<%= button_tag "c" %> <script> VALUE="  c  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '' "> </script>
```

This is going to output something like the following:

```html
<button name="button" type="submit">c</button><script>VALUE="  c  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '' "></script>
```

It looks like you're trying to set attributes of the `<button>` in an unrelated script tag, because you think the `<button>` tag is still open, but that's not the case.  How would that even work? You've specified the content of the button, `c`, so of course it has to output the entire tag. `button_tag` outputs a *complete* tag, including the closing tag. You're not inside an open `<button`, and even if you were, you'd be output horribly broken html because you're wrapping things in a random unnecessary `<script>` tag.

So, what's really going on is you have a `<button>` that doesn't do anything, and an unrelated `<script>` tag that contains this blob of invalid JavaScript:

```
  VALUE="  c  " OnClick="Calc.Input.value += '' ">
```

You're not inside the `<button>` tag any more, you're inside a `<script>` tag, so you can't just set arbitrary attributes on some random other tag. You also cannot nest `<script>` tags inside *the attributes* of another tag.

If you were to actually write this in HTML, you'd want something like the following:

```
<button value="c" onclick="Calc.Input.value += ''">c</button>
```

No `<script>` tags anywhere in sight, because that's not what `<script>` tags are for. If you're going to write inline JavaScript, you can just write it, you don't inject script tags into attributes.

That said, you shouldn't write inline JavaScript. You should be giving your buttons unique IDs, and then binding unobtrusive JavaScript handlers to them:

```
<script>
$('button1').click(function () { Calc.Input.value += ''; });
<script>

<button id="button1">c</button>
```

If you want to use the Rails helper, you'd write it something like this:

```
<%= button_tag 'c', value: '  c  ', onclick: 'Calc.Input.value += ""' %>
```

But again, you shouldn't use inline `onclick` attributes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response; you are most helpful.  With your advice, I am now getting it to appear in the text box but only for a brief second and then it disappears.  Do you happen to know why that is?

Comment: <%= button_tag '7', value: ' 7 ', :id => 'button7', onclick: 'Calc.Input.value += "7"' %><script>    
$('button7').click(function () { Calc.Input.value += '7'; });
<script>

Comment: You need an `onclick` attribute **or** externally-bound handlers using jQuery, not both. You also aren't selecting the element correctly, selecting by id is done with `#`. You need `$('#button7')`. If you have more questions, please ask another question rather than posting them as comments.